# jquery textarea selector issue

Tags: jquery, html, forms, css-selectors

I have a list of results. Within these results there is a `<textarea>` included for each of them. (multiple textareas)

```
<textarea class="form-control smstext" 
          data-sms="<?php echo"$id"; ?>" 
          name="sms-<?php echo"$id"; ?>" 
          id="sms-<?php echo"$id"; ?>" 
          onkeyup="checkSmsText();"  
          onchange="checkSmsText();">
</textarea>
```

I have a problem with getting the value of the `data-sms`-attribute and as a result the `$id` number.

jquery:

```
function checkSmsText() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var id = elem.attr('data-sms');
    console.log(id);
    sms = $('#sms-' + id).val();  
    console.log(sms);
}
```

I tried multiple options know to me, without a success. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Can you inspect and check if `data-sms="<?php echo"$id"; ?>" ` the value for data-sms in the HTML has any spaces?

Comment: Can't you just use `$(this).val()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `<?php echo"$id"; ?>` is wrong(syntax-error).

Add space there like:-

```
<?php echo $id; ?>
```

2. pass `this` as a reference to the function and use them into javascript code.

```js
function checkSmsText(elem) {
  var id = $(elem).attr('data-sms');// better to use $(elem).data('sms');
  console.log(id);
  sms = $(elem).val();  
  console.log(sms);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control smstext" data-sms="1" name="sms-1" id="sms-1" onkeyup="checkSmsText(this);" onchange="checkSmsText(this);"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **data="sms-"** instead of **data-sms=""**